# Difference between MKL numpy from Conda and Gohlke's distributions

Tags: numpy, pip, anaconda, conda

I've setup a conda environment and used `conda install numpy`. This includes the `mkl` package, which is quite large, 100s of MBs.  Conda installs these into `Library/bin` in the environment when on Windows.  In another conda environment I installed numpy+mkl from  [Christoph Gohlke's binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).  What's the difference between these two numpy builds that are both linked against MKL?  Is there a preferred version to use?

The install from Christoph's binaries don't put all the `mkl_*` DLLs in `Library/bin`.  Christoph's website says all the MKL libraries are included in the numpy.core folder after the `pip install`.  I checked and there are a few DLL files in there, but none with the `mkl_*` prefix.

The conda version ends up using 100s of MBs more than the other install so I'm curious what benefits there are to using the Conda version.

Comment: One benefit is that the Conda `numpy` will for sure work with the Conda `scipy`, `scikit-*`, etc. libraries, where Christoph's might not, depending on the details of how all the packages are linked to the underlying libraries and how they're loaded on your OS.

Comment: I'm planning on only using libraries from Christoph's distribution if it really saves 100s of MBs. Guess it's safe to assume if I use all the libraries from the same 'distribution' they should play nice together?

Comment: It seems you are comparing the binaries for Python 2.7. In that case, the gohlke binaries are statically linked to MKL and don't include the MKL DLLs. If you are using conda/Anaconda, better use the numpy binaries provided by conda/Anaconda.

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks for the info and all your builds!! So I if I'm not using conda there's no benefit to their setup?  I can use either one, but I'm leaning towards using yours since they are so much smaller. Is there a downside to not having the stand-alone MKL DLLs?